# Why doesn't Mongoose call "callback"?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a very strange question:

In my "Message.js" file I've defined a schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const moment = require('moment');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MessageSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Cannot Be Empty!']
  },
  type: {                                               
    type: Number,
    enum: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  target: { type: [], default: ['all'] },
  target_user: { type: [], default: ['all'] },
  ext: {},
  create_time: {
    type: Number,
    default: function () {
      return moment().unix();
    }
  }
});

const MessageModel = mongoose.model("MessageModel", MessageSchema);
module.exports = MessageModel;
```

And then I've referred this file in another model by using codes like this following:

```
const MessageModel = require('../../common/model').MessageModel;

exports.messageList = function (req, res) {

.....

  MessageModel.find(queryParams).skip(offset)
    .limit(limit)
    .sort({ create_time: -1 })
    .exec(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.error(err);
      }
      else {
        res.success(data);
      }
    });
};
```

What surprised me is that the callback at "exec" is NEVER called,which means the res would never be called to return the actual values. I tried "findOne","remove"....ect. They are all fine with me EXCEPT find in Visual Studio Code.... Why?

Can anyone lend me a hand? Reguards!

Answer (score 0):

You can try then(). it's better approach

```
const MessageModel = require('../../common/model').MessageModel;

exports.messageList = function (req, res) {
MessageModel.find(queryParams).skip(offset)
 .limit(limit)
 .sort({ create_time: -1 })
 .then((data) => {
   if (data) {
     res.status(200).json(data);
   } 
   else {
     res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server error'});
   }
 });
};
```

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't help :(